# Angularjs 1.7.x, How can I caught success after method executed, provided the method is executed from other file nd has its own success handler?

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.uploadAppFile = function(element) {
            console.log("uploadAppFile : selectedAppId "+$scope.selectedAppId);
            $rootScope.uploadFile(element.files, $scope.selectedAppId, element.id, $scope,false);
        }
```

Above is my uploadAppFile code from upload.js file, I am invoking rootScope js file API.

```
$rootScope.uploadFile = function(files, applicationId, documentId, scope, isUserDoc) {
            if ($rootScope.isEmpty(documentId)) {
                Notification.warning("Document id is null or empty !!");
                return;
            }
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", files[0]);
            var data = {};
            data.applicationId = applicationId;
            data.documentId = documentId;
            if(isUserDoc != undefined && isUserDoc != null){
                data.isUserDocument = isUserDoc;    
            }
            formData.append("uploadRequest", JSON.stringify(data));

            $http({
                method : "POST",
                enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
                url : URLS.user + "/upload",
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : undefined,
                    'token' : $cookieStore.get(Constant.TOKEN)
                },
                data : formData,
                processData : false,
                cache : false
            })
                .then(
                    function success(response) {
                        if (response.data.status == 200) {
                            if (response.data.data.isFileUpload) {
                                Notification.info("Successfully Uploaded !!");

                            } else {
                                Notification.warning("File can't uploaded !!");
                            }

                        } else if (response.data.status == 400) {
                            Notification.warning(response.data.message);
                        }
                    }, function errorCallback(error) {
                        $rootScope.validateErrorResponse(error);
                    });
        }
```

Above is my rootScope.js file where upload file method is declared.

I wanted to make call from my upload.js file as below, external success caught

$rootScope.uploadFile(element.files, $scope.selectedAppId, element.id, $scope,false)**.then(function(success){//Do stuff here})**;

Is this possible, because I want to check once file uploded then enable few options on UI, I dont want modify rootScope.js as it is common and generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Define a service or a factory instead. Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

Return a promise on success/fail using

```
return $q.resolve()
```

or

```
return $q.reject();
```

and remember to add return on the http also. after that you can do a .then on the caller (uploadFiles).

I know you said not to modify rootScope.js however there is no other way to be notified of an async task completion, without you doing sending some kind of a message back and forth either via event or promise.

Anyway, if you really wanted to not change rootScope.js, you can just do some kind of nasty loop and wait for the notification with a message to show up :) (extremely Do Not recommend this, don't do it.)

Code below on what it should look like with promise. (remember to inject $q)

```
 $rootScope.uploadFile = function(files, applicationId, documentId, scope, isUserDoc) {
                if ($rootScope.isEmpty(documentId)) {
                    Notification.warning("Document id is null or empty !!");
                    return $q.reject();
                }
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", files[0]);
                var data = {};
                data.applicationId = applicationId;
                data.documentId = documentId;
                if(isUserDoc != undefined && isUserDoc != null){
                    data.isUserDocument = isUserDoc;    
                }
                formData.append("uploadRequest", JSON.stringify(data));

               return $http({
                    method : "POST",
                    enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
                    url : URLS.user + "/upload",
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : undefined,
                        'token' : $cookieStore.get(Constant.TOKEN)
                    },
                    data : formData,
                    processData : false,
                    cache : false
                })
                    .then(
                        function success(response) {
                            if (response.data.status == 200) {
                                if (response.data.data.isFileUpload) {
                                    Notification.info("Successfully Uploaded !!");
                                    return $q.resolve();
                                } else {
                                    Notification.warning("File can't uploaded !!");
                                    return $q.reject();
                                }
                            } else if (response.data.status == 400) {
                                Notification.warning(response.data.message);
                                return $q.reject();
                            }
                        }, function errorCallback(error) {
                            $rootScope.validateErrorResponse(error);
                            return $q.reject();
                        });
            }

$scope.uploadAppFile = function(element) {
                console.log("uploadAppFile : selectedAppId "+$scope.selectedAppId);
                $rootScope.uploadFile(element.files, $scope.selectedAppId, element.id, $scope,false)
                .then(function(){
                    //success
                }, function(){
                    //failed
                });
            }
```

This wont break any existing usage of the rootScope.js files. There are more optimizations to be made however, this should answer your question